# Mac mini 2014 not booting Ubuntu 14.04 (no dual boot)

Tags: boot, uefi, partitioning, mbr, mac-mini

I just installed Ubuntu from a live usbkey on my brand new mac mini. Clean install to main HD with no dual boot or funny business: I plan on booting Ubuntu from the internal HD and connecting an external drive when i need to run OSX.

Setup goes through normally but afterwards it won't boot up (I get the question mark icon, sometimes a blank screen). I tried twice already. The live usbkey works flawlessly when I use it to test the system around so I don't understand why using the internal HD should create any troubles.
I took a pic of my HD partitions with Gparted after the installaion since I'm guessing it's probably a problem with partition tables/file systems, etc.

[partitions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o07e9ebho2x7szy/gparted.png?dl=0)

Any ideas? THX in advance!